# Including Javascript on all websites on machine

Tags: c#, c++, window

I noticed that when using a 3G dongle to access the web. A javacript script is included at the end of any page that I visit. but just for (html, htm, php, asp, aspx). The script adds the functionality to download reduced quality images instead of full size, to save on bandwidth. However, it's function is irrelevant to my question.

I need to be able to do the same thing. For any request that comes into my machine, I would like a javascript include. But not a BHO or browser extention.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: I'm not sure if the dongle does HTTPS, but for my purposes it's not necessary. I just want to blank out certain adverts.

Comment: Oh, just for adverts filtering there are many existing solutions. I actually have a few of advertisement domains in my hosts file, pointing to `127.0.0.1`, making them non-loadable by any means.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to write a Web proxy engine to achieve this. Then you would configure it as either a transparent proxy (perhaps you would need to implement a network card driver for this), or configure all browsers on the machine to direct traffic through the proxy.

A 3G dongle may achieve this through various means, e.g. a filter inserted somewhere in the driver software, or may be even some processing occurs right in the hardware (less likely in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going to use FiddlerCore as a service to do this. It seems to be a nice clean way of doing this.

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/